# Selecting NULL values of the particular date

Tags: mysql, date, null

You can get the particular data if date exist in a table row, what **"IF"** it's **"NULL"?** 
Can you get all ***NULL*** data of *today*? Is it possible using **mysql query?**

Edited:

I have a question, can you retrieve data that are not recorded for a certain date?
For example:

1. Janice    Student    2017-xx-xx
2. Paul      Student    2017-xx-xx
3. Mika      Student     ------

You can retrive those records with date, but can you retrive data that have no values? Is it possible using mysql query? or conditional x looping statement using PHP?

Comment: without data to look at all we can say is "probably not"  or "almost certainly not". If a date column IS NULL it s in fact without any value at all, so you cannot locate rows "of today" with the same date column being NULL. **But if you show some rows of data in your question maybe there is a way to help....**

Comment: As per my thinking you are using your data for some processing, so just check in your DB whether any records present in DB then use it other wise define NULL variables by default in your programming language and then use it.

Comment: @Kishan oh I get it, thanks for that

Comment: @Used_By_Already  thanks tho, It's just a thought

Comment: If you have a timestamp column you could default that column to current_timestamp so that at any insert it would be "today". Otherwise any other method really isn't going to be completely reliable.

Comment: @Used_By_Already wait I'll edit my question, Null is not the right term for it.

Comment: done @Used_By_Already

Answer (score 1):

To locate information where there is no value stored use **IS NULL** e.g.

```
select * from yourtable where column_name IS NULL
```

If the column is a string of some type then it might be an "empty string", which looks like no value but isn't NULL, so for this use:

```
select * from yourtable where column_name = ''
```

or in combination:

```
select * from yourtable where ( column_name IS NULL OR column_name = '' )
```

Comment: this is helpful but I was asking iif that null is null on the day of 2017-06-06?

Comment: and as I have indicated by comments, if the date column IS NULL it cannot also be "today". What you are asking for isn't possible. On a row, in that date column. there can only be a single value, or NULL. **It cannot be both.**